# How do I get NSNumberFormatter to display the infinity symbol (∞)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

My textfield is mapped to an `NSUInteger` typed property on the model object.  Whenever the property is equal to `NSUIntegerMax`, the textfield's `NSNumberFormatter` displays `-1`.  I'd rather it display `∞`.

I've tried setting the 'Format (-)' value (from IB) to `∞` but the result is `∞1`.  There are methods to define the symbol to use when encountering infinity... but it never gets used.  If not `NSUIntegerMax`, which value actually results in the infinity symbol??

Comment: An *unsigned* number is displayed as -1?? That suggests something is wrong to me! What does `NSUIntegerMax-1` display as? (It may be that `NSNumberFormatter` is broken for unsigned numbers.)

Comment: Confirmed, `NSNumberFormatter` doesn't understand *unsigned*, all values from `NSUIntegerMax/2+1` to `NSUIntegerMax` are displayed as negative (i.e. it is interpreting the bit pattern as a signed number). Doesn't solve your ∞ problem of course. `NSNumberFormatter` insists on there being some digits printed, and will print as many as needed before a decimal point. Time to write your own formatter.

Comment: i just found out that if your subclass of NSNumberFormatter has a maximum, you cannot even print the infinity sign in the NSTextField. remove the maximum, and all is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUIntegerMax` is not infinity, it's just a big number. Floating point numbers (`float` or `double`) do have special values to represent infinity, and for those the number formatter will use the given infinity symbols.

To give the infinity symbol for `NSUIntegerMax` you'll either have to write your own number formatter or handle this case separately.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "infinity" in the integer space. Only floats have the concept of "infinity" (and also "NaN" or "not a number"). `NSUIntegerMax` is definitely not infinity (it's infinitely smaller than infinity).

If you'd like to map a finite integer to the string `∞`, then you need to either convert to floats and use `INFINITY` or you need to subclass `NSNumberFormatter` to override `stringForObjectValue:` to do what you want. Or you can manage it at a higher level if you like and just check things before handing them to your `NSNumberFormatter`.